# How should you handle routes in NEXTJS api?

Tags: next.js

I've seen it done 2 ways. Which one is correct. or what's the difference between the two?

1 make a /api/pages

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    // Process a POST request
  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
  }
}
```

2 make a /api/pages/route.js file

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://data.mongodb-api.com/...', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'API-Key': process.env.DATA_API_KEY,
    },
  })
  const data = await res.json()
 
  return NextResponse.json({ data })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct depends on what router are you using,

The first approach is used by Pages Router

Any file inside the folder pages/api is mapped to /api/* and will be treated as an API endpoint instead of a page. They are server-side only bundles and won't increase your client-side bundle size.

For example, the following API route pages/api/user.js returns a json response with a status code of 200:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

For an API route to work, you need to export a function as default (a.k.a request handler), which then receives the following parameters:

To handle different HTTP methods in an API route, you can use req.method in your request handler, like so:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    // Process a POST request
  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
  }
}
```

and Second Approach is for App router

Route Handlers are defined in a route.js|ts file inside the app directory:
app/api/route.js

Route Handlers can be nested inside the app directory, similar to page.js and layout.js. But there cannot be a route.js file at the same route segment level as page.js.

Route Handlers are statically evaluated by default when using the GET method with the Response object.
app/items/route.js

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://data.mongodb-api.com/...', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'API-Key': process.env.DATA_API_KEY,
    },
  })
  const data = await res.json()
 
  return NextResponse.json({ data })
}
```